# Link in chat message not expanded?

Tags: support, chat, hyperlinks

I was just trying out chat for the first time and because I wanted to make a comment on an answer I started my message with a link to that answer. I typed: `http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/805/99` but to my surprise the link was not expanded. The [permalink](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9090700#9090700) to the chat message just shows it as plain text and in the chatroom the link is shown as  'sustainability.stackexchange...' (clickable link). Is this a bug? Shouldn't the link automatically have expanded?

I've tested some links in [the chat sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9090782#9090782) and there all links were expanded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expected it to be one-boxed, then that only works for urls *on their own*.

Any multi-line message is assumed to be a pasted message and all formatting is disabled. Only indented messages are then still formatted, but as code.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thx!